# Admin grid collection addFieldToFilter no working with dynamic data

Tags: custom-admin-grid

I'm facing an strange issue in fetching filtered data in admin grid. I had tried to filter the collection using _initSelect function

**<Module>\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Collection.php**

```
<?php

namespace <vendor>\<module>\Model\ResourceModel\Custom;

use <vendor>\<module>\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'event_id';
    protected $_previewFlag;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('<vendor>\<module>\Model\Custom', '<vendor>\<module>\Model\ResourceModel\Custom');
    }
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
        $event_id =  1;
        $request->getParam('event_id');
        $this->addFieldToFilter("event_entity_id", $event_id);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

It's working with static event_id but, not able to fetch when I try it with dynamic event_id via request params.

Let me know If anything is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using mentioned below steps

1. Store param value in session in the controller

> public function execute() {
> $this->_catalogSession->setTokenId($this->request->getParam('entity_id'));
> $this->_view->loadLayout(); $this->_view->loadLayoutUpdates();
> $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Redeem Token
> History')); $this->_view->renderLayout(); }

2. Use session value in data provider

> $tokensCollection->addFieldToFilter('token_id', ['eq' =>
> $this->_catalogSession->getTokenId()]);